# “ist gefegt” vs. “hat gefegt”

Tags: perfect-tense

I’m assuming the following translations are reasonable:

> Sie fegte über die Bühne. → She swept across the stage.
>
> Sie fegte die Bühne. → She swept the stage.

The conjugation in an online resource gives these two alternatives: *ist gefegt* and *hat gefegt.*

Would I be right in surmising that the first alternative applies to the first usage above and the second to the second?
Thus:

> Sie ist über die Bühne gefegt.
>
> Sie hat die Bühne gefegt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja, die Vermutung ist absolut richtig.

> Sie ist über die Bühne gefegt.

means acting,

> Sie hat die Bühne gefegt.

means to do the cleaning.

Answer (score 8):

Your surmise seems right to me.

One of the cases where one should use "sein" for perfect tense is:

- With action verbs that denote a change of place and not necessarily just movement, e.g. tanzen

So, in your example, the verb "fegen" is conjugated in perfect tense using "sein" when it denotes a change of place or movement. For the other usage it's conjugated using "haben":

> Sie **ist** über die Bühne gefegt: She swept across the stage.
>
> Sie **hat** die Bühne gefegt: She swept the stage.

Also, reading [an article about "Sein" and "Haben"](http://german.about.com/od/verbs/a/German-Grammar-Tip.htm) would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, my first thought was: you're right.
"Sie fegte über die Bühne." translates as "She ran across the stage.", which describes a movement like "Sie ist gelaufen" ("She walked"). Whereas the second "Sie fegte die Bühne" means - as you wrote - "She swept the stage", which is more of a crafting act like "She painted the stage" ("Sie hat die Bühne gestrichen").

Comment: But what about "ist" versus "hat"?  Is my surmise correct?  I.e. "ist" is used when it's like "laufen" and "hat" when it's like "strichen"?

Comment: The way you said "my first thought was [...]" made me expect a sentence like "but then I changed my mind"!

Comment: @Gigili, I wanted to express the sudden feeling of "correctness" I had when I read the question.

Comment: @CoffinwoodBlackheim: I see, I only got the impression, no offence.